# SharePoint Online JSON Wrap Code with fetched HTML

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, html

I have a SharePoint Online List linked to a Power App. When I enter Comments in the Power App, the comments get flooded over to SharePoint list.

However, when the comments get populated in the SharePoint list using the following JSON code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style":{
        "white-space":"wrap"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

I get the follwing output in SharePoint:

[image: SharePoint Column Screenshot]

How can I pull over the HTML formatted text from my Power App as regular text?

Comment: Multi-line Rich text fields are not supported in List Formatting and will always render this way. They will look ok if you remove the format.

Comment: What is the column type (data type) of "Comments" column? Are you adding comments using rich text control (HTML text control) from Power apps?

Answer (score 0):

In your PowerApp, you can try wrapping your text in PlainText() and see if that produces the desired result. In my experience, it does an ok job but it isn't perfect.